# How do I get a Slax module game to run?

Tags: linux, slax

I am new to Linux. I have purchased a USB stick with Slax on it. I downloaded some modules and placed them in the modules folder. Can someone tell me how to run the modules, what commands do you use and where do you use them? Can you tell me how to get Breakout working, for example?

I can boot from the USB stick and get on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading through the documentation [here](http://www.slax.org/en/documentation.php) I found that slax needs the modules 'activated'. To 'activate' a module you can perform a reboot or use the Software Center to manually activate it. The documentation also notes you can activate the module from the command line:

```
slax activate [ file or name ]
```

Afterwards, you should be able to run it like normal Linux software. If you are lucky, your desktop environment will automatically add an entry to the menu and you can click and enjoy. Otherwise, open a terminal and type the name of the software (always one word).

As for breakout working, I think you mean `lbreakout2`. First you will need the module that it 'requires' (the dependency) which is `sdl`. So you can install it from the Software Center or download it manually and place it in  `/slax/modules/` and do a reboot. Repeat the process with the `lbreakout2` module. It should now be visible in your KDE menu. If it isn't, just type

```
lbreakout2
```

in the command-line and enjoy!